# Is there a complete DOM Inheritance structure diagram somewhere?

Tags: javascript, dom, browser

The MDN pages contain information about the DOM API interfaces and the inheritance relationships between then. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model

The best graphical representation I have found is the following:

[image: Archive.org link of an MSDN image showing an example of a DOM tree from 2015 or earlier]

But is there a more complete diagram that shows the inheritance relationships between most of the interfaces on the MDN page linked above? Or is there a software that can generate such a diagram? Where else besides the MDN pages can one find the inheritance structure between DOM interfaces?

If a more complete visualization of the inheritance structure cannot be found, is anyone willing to help me create such a graphic? Any volunteer would like to upload a list of the DOM APIs along with parent of each API?

Answer (score 9):

I had been playing recently with [extracting information from W3C specs](https://www.w3.org/blog/2016/07/exploring-web-platform-cross-dependencies/), and wondered how quickly I could build this with the extracted data.

In short, not long at all (in big parts because d3 is such an impressive visualization library): https://dontcallmedom.github.io/webidlpedia/inheritance.html 
[image: Screnshot of Tree visualization of inheritance in DOM interfaces]

Code available on https://github.com/dontcallmedom/webidlpedia

Comment: Very interesting! https://dontcallmedom.github.io/webidlpedia/graph-cyto.html could use a layout algorithm though

Comment: yeah, I'm not too happy with the dependencies graph, but haven't found the right approach to visualize such a big mesh. If you have suggestions, I'll happily take them :)

Comment: There's also `SVGElement` and descendants

Comment: This is wonderful! Once you finish this project, you should put a link to your code and a screenshot on the the corresponding MDN page https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model

Comment: What is the inheritance hierarchy for EventTarget? Where should it fit on the diagram above? There is no such information about that API here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.

Comment: I have updated the tree to start from `EventTarget` (from which `Node` inherits); this brings in quite a few more non-DOM interfaces though.

Comment: For anyone that is looking for a working version of this, I forked the repo and tidied up a little here: https://t99.github.io/webidlpedia/